# list contains an ID in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to find a linq query so I can write it in an if statement.

Pseudo code:

IDList is a list of ints List< int >

```
if (IDList.Contains (Object.Id)) Do something
```

but I can't seem to work out what need.

In none-linq this works:

```
  foreach(int id in IDList )
     {
        if (id == Object.Id)
            break;
     }
```

but I want it as one line if possible.

I first tried this:

```
IDList.Contains(Object.Id);
```

but this throws a compile error

I'm wondering should it be one of these two?

```
  IDList.Any(id => id == Object.Id)
```

or

```
IDList.Exists(id => id == Object.Id);
```

I don't completely understand how the lambdas and things work or the difference between andy and exists so I'm not sure if I'm along the wrong line?

Comment: What you want to do can you explain that logically because this is not clear in the question

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
if (MyList.Any(c => c.Id == MyObject.Id)) { }
```

Assuming that `MyList` is an `IEnumerable<T>` (or anything that derives from `IEnumerable<T>`) where T is an object that has a property named `Id` of the same type of the property `Id` on the `MyObject` instance.

Answer (score 8):

```
 IDList.Any(id => id == Object.Id)
```

Is ok, it will return you `true` if at least one element, that satisfies your predicate, exists.